# Kotlin reflection change instance and all members that use the instance

Tags: reflection, kotlin

We are using reflection to enable our tests to be started in different environments.

A typical test would look like this:

```
class TestClass {
  val environment: Environment = generateEnvironment("jUnit")
  val path: String = environment.path

  //Do test stuff
}
```

We are using reflection like this:

```
class PostgresqlTest{
  val classList: List<KClass<*>> = listOf(TestClass::class)
  val postgresEnv = generateEnvironment("postgres")

  @TestFactory
  fun generateTests(): List<DynamicTest> = classList.flatMap { testClass ->
    val instance = testClass.createInstance()
    environmentProperty(testclass).setter.call(instance, postgresEnv)

    //<<generate the dynamic tests>>

  }

  fun environmentProperty(testClass: KClass<*>) = 
    testClass.memberProperties.find {
      it.returnType.classifier == Environment::class
  } as KMutableProperty<*>
}
```

Now we have the issue that `path != environment.path` in the PostgresqlTest

I know this can be solved in the TestClass with lazy or get() like this

```
class TestClass {
  val environment: Environment = generateEnvironment("jUnit")

  val path: String by lazy { environment.path }

  // OR

  val path: String get() = environment.path
}
```

However this seems like a potential pitfall for future developers, especially since the first code snippet will work in TestClass and only fail for the tests where the environment is overwritten.

What is the cleanest way to ensure that `path == environment.path` when overwritting the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new test-task in gradle for each environment:

```
task postgresqlIntegrationTest(type: Test, group: "Verification", description: "Runs integration tests on postgresql.") {
    dependsOn compileTestKotlin
    mustRunAfter test

    environment "env", "postgresql"

    useJUnitPlatform {
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching "*IT"
        }
    }
}
```

where my testclass just loads the environment like this:

```
class TestClass {
  val environment: Environment = generateEnvironment(System.getenv("env") ?: "junit")
  //Do test stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you're using a dependency injection framework (e.g. Dagger) you would want the test classes to just inject the `Environment` (which would allow referencing the environment path only after it's provided), for example:

```
class TestClass {
  @Inject lateinit var environment: Environment
  private lateinit var path: String

  @Before fun setup() {
    // do injection here
    path = environment.path
  }
}
```

Otherwise, I think interface delegation could be a good option here and avoids reflection entirely. For instance, create an `EnvironmentHost` which surfaces an `environment` and `path` property:

```
interface EnvironmentHost {
  var environment: Environment
  val path: String
}
```

Create an implementation here for test classes:

```
class TestEnvironmentHost : EnvironmentHost {
  override var environment: Environment = generateEnvironment("jUnit")
  override val path: String
    get() = environment.path
}
```

Test classes now can look like:

```
class TestClass : EnvironmentHost by TestEnvironmentHost() {
  @Test fun myTest() {
    val myPath = path
    val myEnvironment = environment
  }
}
```

And your test factory can be simplified to:

```
@TestFactory
fun generateTests(): List<DynamicTests> = classList.flatMap { testClass ->
  val instance = testClass.createInstance()

  // Assign an environment if the test is an EnvironmentHost. If not,
  // you could choose to treat that as a failure and require the test
  // class to be an EnvironmentHost.
  (instance as? EnvironmentHost)?.environment = postgresEnv

  ...
}
```